# How to Re-use data generated by one Response to other request?

Tags: jmeter

In my application while executing the first request one unique key is generated which key is required for Next all the request. let me how to automate such scenario in Jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process should look as follows:

1. Add [Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to the first request
2. Configure it to extract the required value and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. Use JMeter Variable from step 2 in your next request.

Depending on response data type you have the following choices:

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - for text
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) - for HTML
- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) - for XML and XHTML
- [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) - for JSON
- It is also possible to [extract data from files](https://blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) i.e. if response is in PDF format, but it's a little bit tricky

---

Example configuration to store the whole response:

- Reference Name: any suitable variable name, i.e. `response`
- Regular Expression: `(?s)(^.*)`
- Template: `$1$`

You can refer the extracted value as `${response}` where required. You can also amend the regular expression to extract response part instead of the whole response. JMeter uses Perl5-compatible regular expressions, see [Regular Expressions User Manual Chapter for details](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **regular expression extractor** to extract the key from the response of your first request and use the extracted key for subsequent requests. To achieve this:

1. Right click on the first request and add post processor: Regular Expression Extractor.
   [image]
2. Create your regular expression and provide values in other required fields. Please refer to JMeter component reference http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor
   [image]
3. Extracted value will be saved in the variable given as reference name
   Use this variable in subsequent requests
   [image]

Here is an [example test plan with results](https://www.redline13.com/LoadTest/View/23024).